# In the evenings vs. every evening

Tags: sentence-meaning

This sentence meaning question:

> My grandmother is always at home **in the evenings.**

To

> My grandmother is always at home **every evenings.**

What's the difference between the two? It seems to me that they are similar in context, BUT I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference in their meaning apart from grammar. Your two sentences can be

> My grandmother is always at home in the evening.
>
> My grandmother is at home every evening.

They are different ways of saying the same thing, although the second example flows a bit better.

Answer (score 1):

"Always at home every evenings" is not grammatical.  Also, using both "always" and "every" in the same sentence is redundant.  We would be more likely to say:

> My grandmother is at home **every evening**.

or

> My grandmother is **always** at home **in the evening**.

Otherwise, there's no real difference between the two expressions. This also goes for other time frames, like *morning* or *afternoon*.